# Need Code Coverage for Wrapper class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I have a wrapper class. I am trying to cover the code coverage.

Apex Class:

```
public class AccountRelatedListController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static list<DataTableWrapper> getServiceAppointmentList(Id accId)

{
List<ServiceAppointment> saList = [select id,Status,Individual_Name__c,SchedStartTime,AppointmentNumber,AccountId from ServiceAppointment where AccountId =: accId];    


List<DataTableWrapper> response = new List<DataTableWrapper>();
for(ServiceAppointment sa : saList)
{
DataTableWrapper obj = new DataTableWrapper();
obj.saId = sa.Id;
obj.AppointmentNumber = sa.AppointmentNumber;
obj.AppointmentNumberUrl = '/' + sa.Id;
obj.Individual = sa.Individual_Name__c;
obj.ScheduledStart = sa.SchedStartTime;
obj.Status = sa.Status;
response.add(obj);
}
return response;
}

private class DataTableWrapper
{
@AuraEnabled
public Id saId {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String AppointmentNumber {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String AppointmentNumberUrl {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Individual {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public Datetime ScheduledStart {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Status {get;set;}


}

}
```

---

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class TestAccountRelatedlistController {

    
static testMethod void AccountController()
{
 Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
 insert a;
Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test',LastName = 'One');
insert c;
 List<ServiceAppointment> sa = [Select Id,AppointmentNumber, 
ContactId,Status,SchedStartTime from ServiceAppointment where 
AccountId=:a.Id and ContactId=:c.Id];
 insert sa;
  Test.startTest();
    
     AccountRelatedListController.getServiceAppointmentList(a.Id);
  Test.stopTest();  
}
}
```

Iam new to test classes and I've tried like this above test class and code coverage is upto 30%.Can anyone help that how to cover remaining part. Its covering 'getServiceAppointmentList' is not covering 'DataTableWrapper' part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create a ServiceAppointment record in your unit test class. This also means you probably want to create a Contact record as well. Also, note that `testMethod` is deprecated; use `@isTest` instead.

---

```
class TestAccountRelatedlistController {

@isTest static void AccountController()
{
     Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
     insert a;
     Contact c = new Contact(AccountId=a.Id,...);
     insert c;
     ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment(ContactId=c.Id,...);
     insert sa;
     Test.startTest();
     AccountRelatedListController.getServiceAppointmentList(a.Id);
     Test.stopTest();  
   }
}
```

Comment: @HemanthPetlu You need to make the class public.

Comment: @HemanthPetlu You can't query most types of records in unit tests because of [database isolation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). You must *create* new ServiceAppointment records directly, rather than attempting to query them.

Comment: I have testdata factory, so only i am querying service appointments. Can you tell how to cover for loop / wrapper class instance

Comment: @HemanthPetlu I don't see you calling any such factory, though. The loop is not covered because there is no data to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now i edited the test class code with testdatafactory, as i used testsetup annotation i am querying the ServiceAppointments data. And can i  know how to cover the loop. can you give me the instance how to cover the for loop

Comment: @HemanthPetlu Since you created data in your testSetup method, you should query the account and contact in your unit test method, rather than creating new accounts and contacts.

Comment: Not a huge fan of posting an answer on questions of this style without even mentioning the lack of assertions.

Comment: Oh thanks for replying but i solved it